# Yaml output filled with !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, yaml

I upgraded to rails 3.0.9 and there is a new yaml gem. Unfortunately the way to_yaml is outputting a rather large hash has changed somehow. Now, I am getting a lot of "!map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess" after elements that I wasn't getting before which as far as I am concerned is a bug because I am trying to make my .yml as human readable as possible. Is there a way to get rid of "!map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess" from the yaml output? It doesn't affect the way it is loaded into my code so I don't see the point having it in the output. I could just gsub it out but I think there is something else happening here that I am unaware of.

Typical hash input:

```
{"All" => 
  {"A test" => {"string"=>"This is just a test",
               "description" => "This is a description for a test string",
               "alternatives" => [{"new" => "woot"}]}}
```

Yaml output:

```
All:
  A test: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    string: This is just a test
    description: This is a description for a test string
    alternatives:
    - !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      new: woot
```

What I want (and what I was getting before):

```
All:
  A test:
    string: This is just a test
    description: This is a description for a test string
    alternatives:
      - new: woot
```

Note: My output must be in UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your hash comes from `params` in controller, which has the type `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`. One way to fix the output is by monkey patching its `to_yaml` method to convert itself to normal hash before converting it to YAML.

```
# config/initializers/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
class HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash
  def to_yaml(opts = {})
    self.to_hash.to_yaml(opts)
  end
end
```

Comment: The fix works. Yeah, my hash is from `params` in the controller. Is there a way to change this in the controller?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to change that. The reason they use `HashWithIndifferentAccess` is so that you can access the values using string or symbol as the key, for example: `params[:user]` or `params['user']`.

Comment: In my opinion we should think several times before *monkey patch* any shared class. We are not sure which gem or plugin is gonna fail because our modifications.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same issue, I have been thinking in the **@htanata** solution, also is possible to implement this *monkey patch*:

```
class HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash
  def to_yaml_typea
    ""
  end
end
```

But it is also very danger.

I have been thinking in implement my [own YAML::Emitter](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/custom-yaml-emitter.html) but it looked like technology overkill.

This also worked:

```
JSON.parse(my_hash_with_indifferent_access.to_json).to_yaml
```

But didn't look too much efficient :)

Also crossed my mind:

```
my_hash_with_indifferent_access.to_yaml.gsub( " !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess", "" )
```

Still thinking is a possibility but all of us agree that this smells bad.

**My final solution has been**:

```
# config/intializers/hash_with_indifferent_access_extension.rb
# use it like `params.to_hash_recursive.to_yaml`
class HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash
  def to_hash_recursive
    result = self.to_hash

    result.each do |key, value|
      if(value.is_a? HashWithIndifferentAccess)
        result[key] = value.to_hash_recursive
      end
    end

    result
  end
end
```

It is also a *monkey patch* but at least it is monkey patching a **non-existing method** so the possibilities to interfere with third party code behavior is very weird.

*PD*: any suggestion for cleaning up this code please refer to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1540618)